# How to setup erpnext with Static IP

Tags: ip, live, static-ip-address, erpnext

Now I Want To Intergrate My Erpnext To Static IP Address?? What Are Stepa Are Provided For That Intergration??Please Give The Infromation Cleaarly And Useful To me…
Thanks

I have 4 IP poll from ISP (Pakistan Telecomunication Company Limited). How to configure.